# Large complex pattern query not returning on 2.2.1+, and does (slowly) on 2.2.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query someone has autogenerated - and passed on to me as it's not performing well (!!)- this is the setup:

There is a pattern of 16 nodes, with 17 relationships, the direction is *unknown* and spaces between is *unknown* but a maximum of 2 (for example: `(x)-[:R_T*1..2]->(y)`). Now the nodes are not in a simple linear pattern, but could be something more like (excuse the bad ASCII):

```
E<--A-->B
     \->C-->D
```

So I can't just do: `MATCH a--b--c--d--e` etc.
There's more....

Each node should be matched based on a string value, which could *either* be one value, or multiple: (I'm using `n` as a stand in identifier, each node would have it's own identifier, `n1`, `n2` etc)

`WHERE n.Value = 'Hello'`

*or*

`WHERE (n.Value = 'Hello' OR n.Value = 'World')`

There's still more....

Some nodes might want to have the `Value` ignored, and instead `Match` on a different property:

`WHERE (n.SiValue > 4.0) AND (n.SiValue < 6.0)`

To cap it all off, the `RETURN` is two arrays:

`[n1,n2]` etc and `[r1,r2]` (where `r` represents the relationships).

An example query is below, and comes with 1 question:

1. How can this be made better and faster. There must be something that's changeable. For example, aside from the `Match-mare` going on, I know that `MATCH (x2:Node)-[r3:R_T*1..2]-(x3:Node) WHERE (x3.ValueLowercase = "a" OR x3.ValueLowercase = "b")` doesn't match anything - can the query just exit at the first match that doesn't, match.

Things to note:

1. The model isn't changeable and is user generated, the structure is loose intentionally and I know adding direction would speed it up, it's not possible due to the way the query is intended to work.
2. This works on Neo4j 2.2.0 albeit slowly, on 2.2.1+ it never returns - so the presumption is that the parser is doing something different, and my suspicion is that the query is *very* wrong.
3. The query does not have to be like this at all, the `RETURN` needs to have the same content - but I'm pretty certain that if the return structure is different it can be worked in.

And now the query (*for which I can only apologise*):

---

```
MATCH (x0:Node)-[r0:R_T*1..2]-(x2:Node)
WHERE (x0.ValueLowercase = "me")
AND x0.UserId <> "users/7"
MATCH (x0:Node)-[r1:R_T*1..2]-(x9:Node)
MATCH (x0:Node)-[r2:R_T*1..2]-(x1:Node)
MATCH (x2:Node)-[r3:R_T*1..2]-(x3:Node)
WHERE (x3.ValueLowercase = "a" OR x3.ValueLowercase = "b")
MATCH (x2:Node)-[r4:R_T*1..2]-(x6:Node)
WHERE (x6.ValueLowercase = "c" OR x6.ValueLowercase = "d")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r9:R_T*1..2]-(x17:Node)
WHERE (x17.ValueLowercase = "e")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r10:R_T*1..2]-(x11:Node)
WHERE (x11.ValueLowercase = "f")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r11:R_T*1..2]-(x13:Node)
WHERE (x13.ValueLowercase = "g")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r12:R_T*1..2]-(x16:Node)
WHERE (x16.ValueLowercase = "h")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r13:R_T*1..2]-(x15:Node)
WHERE (x15.ValueLowercase = "i")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r14:R_T*1..2]-(x10:Node)
WHERE (x10.ValueLowercase = "j")
MATCH (x9:Node)-[r15:R_T*1..2]-(x14:Node)
WHERE (x14.ValueLowercase = "k")
MATCH (x3:Node)-[r5:R_T*1..2]-(x4:Node)
WHERE (x4.ValueLowercase = "l")
MATCH (x6:Node)-[r7:R_T*1..2]-(x7:Node)
WHERE (x7.ValueLowercase = "m" OR x7.ValueLowercase = "n")
MATCH (x4:Node)-[r6:R_T*1..2]-(x5:Node)
WHERE (x5.ValueLowercase = "o")
MATCH (x7:Node)-[r8:R_T*1..2]-(x8:Node)
WHERE (x8.ValueLowercase = "p")
MATCH (x11:Node)-[r16:R_T*1..2]-(x12:Node)
WHERE (x12.ValueLowercase = "q")
MATCH (x2:Node)-[:D_I]-(x2Data0:DataNode)
WHERE x2Data0.Ticks >= 635757120000000000
AND x2Data0.Ticks <= 635757120000000000
MATCH (x2:Node)-[:D_I]-(x2Data1:DataNode)
WHERE x2Data1.Lt1 >= 51.5259
AND x2Data1.Lt1 <= 51.625899999999994
AND x2Data1.Lg1 >= -0.36
AND x2Data1.Lg1 <= -0.26
MATCH (x9:Node)-[:D_I]-(x9Data0:DataNode)
WHERE x9Data0.Ticks >= 0
AND x9Data0.Ticks <= 0
MATCH (x9:Node)-[:D_I]-(x9Data1:DataNode)
WHERE x9Data1.Lt1 >= 51.4542
AND x9Data1.Lt1 <= 51.554199999999994
AND x9Data1.Lg1 >= -0.287
AND x9Data1.Lg1 <= -0.187
MATCH (x1:Node)-[:D_I]-(x1Data0:DataNode)
WHERE x1Data0.SiValue = 4.0
RETURN 
 [x0,x2,x9,x1,x3,x6,x4,x5,x7,x8,x17,x11,x13,x16,x15,x10,x14,x12] AS Nodes,
 [r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16] AS Relationships
```

---

#### Profile of Query

-- Turns out I can't add this as it exceeds the SO limit on size of the content... so it's here instead: http://1drv.ms/1JjIlYn

#### Size wise:

Tiny.

- Node = 324
- DataNode = 78

#### Store Info

Not sure what you're after, but Enterprise 2.2.0 on Windows (!), the store is teensy-tiny

Comment: Can you add a textual profile of the query, more information about the store (also sizes per label) or best the store itself :) (You can also email it to me privately)

Comment: it seems as if the new planner is failing this query, still investigating

Comment: It works in Neo4j 2.3 at least, there the planner returns after a few seconds

Comment: You should use parameter in that query! It might also be better to have the matches together in one pattern first and then filter afterwards.

Comment: Also if the query is generated dynamically and changes with each invocation you have to pay the compiler/planner cost every time, so it might make more sense to write a suitable query by hand and parametrize it (where you also know the directions, rel-types and distances).

Comment: It does normally use parameters, I've taken out the parameters to be able to debug easier...

Comment: In terms of the multiple `MATCH` statements initially (prior to 2.2 I think) Neo4j had a bug that allowed the match to go backwards, this was fixed and that multiple matches had to be introduced to cover it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem in the default planner in 2.2.

Neo4j has 3 query planners:

- rule (historic)
- cost - greedy (first impl of the cost planner)
- cost - idp (current impl of the cost planner)

You can specify the planner by prefixing your query

- with `cypher planner [rule|cost|idp] MATCH ...`
- or going forward: `cypher planner=[rule|cost|idp] MATCH ...`

In your case both `rule` and `idp` succeed in compiling your query in about 12s (which happens only once). Then the actual execution takes 12s with `rule` and 10 milliseconds with `idp`

Comment: Thank you again, switching the planner made the query come back, and I think there are some things I can get sorted with the query to make it a bit more performant as well...